# Extra layer on skin modifier

Tags: modifiers, armature

While following Joey Carlino's [Fast Character Modeling](https://Fast%20character%20creation) I am stuck at the armature. I have not had parenting issues previously, as I select the object/mesh then the armature and parent with automatic weights. I am able to parent and the armature moves the mesh, but there appears to be an **extra layer that appeared from the skin modifier**. After removing the armature, selecting the wrist vertex and moving it on the Z axis, a second layer exists and doesn't move with the vertex. [image: Vertex movement] The armature will parent and move the weighted vertices, but this extra layer is left behind. This happens to both the hands, feet and chest.
[image: Armature works][image: Feet][image: Chest] Even after applying the modifiers (minus the armature) and popping into edit mode, it can be seen that there is a bunch of vertices created on the inside of the mesh. [image: Too Many Vertices]
I am so confused and I have no idea if this is a skin modifier setting a program setting or how/why this is happening. Any help would be immensely appreciated!
Thank you so much in advance!
Here is the blender [FILE](https://%5B%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=jQz8r25Q%22%20/%3E%5D(https://blend-exchange.com/b/jQz8r25Q/)):

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you've done from your description, but firstly the mirror modifier should have been at the top of the stack not after the skin modifier and you should have applied it before clicking 'Create Armature' on the skin modifier panel. Please upload your Blend file so that we can have a look. https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: Incidentally there's no need to parent the armature after creating it. That's done in the skin modifier.

Comment: Thanks, I added the Blender file and changed the order of the modifiers. However, the armature isnt the head issue I'm having (actually just pitched it). Without the armature, there is an extra layer produced. In edit mode, moving ALL the vertices leaves this extra layer stuff behind. Thanks again

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you've done having now downloaded your file. You appear to have applied the skin modifier and the armature bones have disappeared so you're just left with a normal mesh. There's not much we can tell from that Blend file unless you have an earlier version from before the modifiers were applied?

Comment: Having now looked closer in the outliner you've actually hidden the object with all the modifiers (Plane) and enabled the Duplicate which is the one I was looking at that has all but the Armature modifier applied. I've had a play with the Plane object but, even after getting rid of the armature modifier and Vertex Groups and applying the Mirror, I've not managed to get your one posing correctly whereas one I did from scratch following Joey's tutorial works fine. I can only suggest that you start again from scratch. :^(

Comment: Dang, that blows, thank you for trying tho!

Comment: I tried deleting the armature and all the vertex groups from your model then applying the mirror modifier and generating the rig again, but for some reason I couldn't move anything at all in pose mode and I ran out of time so had to give up. :^(